# What's on the recruiters mind ? And How should I approach ? What should I do?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, recruitment, job-change

**Scenario**: I am *not a fresher*, I am a *5+ years experienced professional*. I spent 5+ years in a branded company without any job change. Recently I wanted a job change and I cracked an interview in one of the top big MNC(It's also a brand). I was *approached via the company's Recruitment team* and not via any consultancy. Since I am an *immediate joiner* and my *notice period in previous IT company got over* I am actively looking for a job change. I got placed through college campus recruitment in my first company but now came the days of *virtual interviews* and there isn't any college to help me out with my doubts.

**Problem**: All my negotiations were completed in the MR round itself. Upon asking about the project the manager told it's a good project based on Java and Microservices for some client outside India which we can't reveal as of now. I am happy with what they have offered but this was only a *verbal discussion*. ***The offer letter is yet to be released***.

I am a curious guy who ask questions to get things clarified and make a decision based on it. The problem is now with the recruiter, she is not interested in answering questions like **whether the company have bonds or not, when will the offer letter release, whether I will be working from offices or client location**(client locations are a bit tuff to handle, lots of pressure if you know). Every time I ask these questions she is like you ask ***lot of questions***, ***did you ask these questions when you got recruited in your previous company***. For offer letter she says I am trying my level best. Even the HR/Manager is not approachable as of now since am not into the company yet and I only have to speak with my recruiter.

Why she's not answering my questions is very suspicious to me. I am very worried and depressed about my current situation and don't know what to do. I know the recruiter/top MNC is not fake. The emails I receive are not fake but my questions are legal and I don't want to waste my career even if it is a brand in case if they handover some weird project with outdated technology. I can move on since I know I am a good developer but thinking it's a brand I plan to wait a bit longer. I am about to join a company and I have all the rights to query them.

**Any suggestion will be very helpful**. ***Do you guys find something fishy***? ***Should I stop asking questions***? May be she's not aware about bonds, projects hence she's is not ready to speak but I feel she is a clever person and intents not to answer. ***Does offer letter mentions all the answers to my legal question***? ***And what if I get onboarded to the company and find things are not what I dreamt of can I say no to it within 15-30 days. Will it impact my career in any means***?

Please let me know in case of any queries.

Please, please help me out!

Comment: What does "brand" mean in this context? A well-known company? Also, what is a "bond"? It's not unusual for a recruiter to have absolutely no idea about technology details. They probably get paid on commission and want to do the absolute minimum amount of work. Also, in my experience, the behavior of recruiters is usually not indicative of the company as a whole.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, "brand" means well-known, famous within and outside a country. "Bond" is a legal agreement between you and company, if you leave the company before the bond completes, you need to pay some amount agreed mutually. It is sometimes 1 year or 2 years. I don't know if that exists for an experienced professional like me mainly it is for freshers because the company invests time  and money on them to make them learn.

Comment: Hands up everyone who had been recruited for a particular project and ended up working on a different one...

Comment: @DaveGremlin, lolz, that is totally fine and that is how it should be or else you would not be able to learn. What's wrong is you asked for Java, given a Cobol project, you wanted to work from offices, you have been given a client location, you wanted development and normal shifts given purely outdated support projects and night shifts.

Comment: @lazy_coder  Yes, it's the conflict between us wanting to do all the things you list, and the company trying to maximise income be deploying its 'resources' in the way it sees fit, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to know what the recruiter is thinking.

> How should I approach?

You already have more than once, but you don't seem to like the answers.

> What should I do?

If you feel everything is legit and want the job, then allow the recruiter to work at their own pace and wait for an offer. If not carry on searching for work while you wait.

Sometimes recruiters are just keeping people hanging because they have no idea who will eventually get the offer and they may not even know all the details of the working conditions etc,. So they don't want to invest much time and effort beyond that until it's more solid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "If you feel everything is legit and want the job", I wanted it because it is tuff to get a chance in that company. I cracked the interviews so that I can work for them. But there are few questions which requires clarity because even if the company is huge and well-known I can't waste my career if the project doesn't suits me. Only one question now, does the offer letter contains all the answers like bond details, project details, probation period, notice period, etc.  ?

Comment: Let's take the extreme case, what if I decide to give it a try even if they I am totally unclear about what is in for me. Can I walk away just like that within 10-30 days of my joining the company or at least if they want me to complete the notice period that is also fine, I mean say notice period is of 90 days. If I walk away within 10-15 days, I won't even mention that on my resume and can practice more to get a good one again. Any other problems that can rise out of this situation ?

Comment: @LazyCoder, Right now, you're obviously not a priority for this company. I have a bad feeling about this. Make sure you keep on sending out your resume and make sure you keep on interviewing with other companies (even lesser known companies). And regarding the bond issue, do not accept a job offer until you've received a copy of the contract first (and if the contract refers to the employee manual, make sure they give you a copy of the employee manual as well). As to the rest of your questions, someone from your own country will need to answer them. I assume you're located in India.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, yes I am from India.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of red flags.

She does not have to "try her level best" for an offer letter. It has to be issued by her. If she can't do that, or is not doing that, there are other issues in the picture which she is not discussing with you.

Repeatedly contacting her will not help the situation.
Keep looking around, keep interviewing, and drop her a polite mail after a few days asking when the offer letter would be avaiable.

Keep all further questions regarding the terms of employment to after receiving an actual offer (if you do receive one). That is also the point in time when a lot of your questions will get answered automatically.
For those that don't (and are meaningful/serious), draft a mail and send them to her in a single communication.

Comment: What I meant was, HR cannot refuse to issue an offer letter so long as the recruitment is clear. IF HR is indeed refusing then there are some unsorted issues/red flags.

Comment: There may be a large number of hoops that HR have to jump through before giving an offer letter. Anybody with authority to act on behalf is legally able to issue an offer letter, but there are certainly procedures and processes that need to be followed.